# Nice output of RDD lineage/Spark operator graph

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm interested in a nice and  clear representation of Spark RDD lineages or operator graphs for educational purposes. I tried `.toDebugString()` but I'm having trouble getting it pretty-printed (including line breaks etc.) What is going wrong here?

```
Using Python version 3.6.4 (default, Mar  1 2018 18:36:42)

SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> sc
<SparkContext master=local[*] appName=PySparkShell>
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize(range(10000))
>>> rdd.toDebugString()
b'(4) PythonRDD[1] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []\n |  ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:175 []'
>>> print(rdd.toDebugString())
b'(4) PythonRDD[1] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []\n |  ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:175 []'
>>>
```

Beyond the debug string, are there even better ways of visualizing the graph?

Comment: Why don't you use the Spark UI ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I'm having trouble getting it pretty-printed

Because it is `bytes` object. Just `decode` the result:

```
>>> print(rdd.toDebugString().decode("utf-8"))
(4) PythonRDD[1] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []
 |  ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:489 []
```

> are there even better ways of visualizing the graph?

DAG visualization in the Spark UI is usually more than enough.